# Output Voltage RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, transient, step-response

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble solving this exercise. Could someone show me their approach in solving it? Could really use the help.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Homework questions are allowed here, _provided_ you show your attempt at solving.

Comment: This may help: current in an inductor can't change instantaneously. If you let us know what you know and what your thought process is, maybe we can help you out were you are getting trumped.

Comment: Are you trying to do this by differential equations or Laplace transform?

Answer (score 1):

By now, I can only explain to you the part when the voltage it's 12v.
According to the diagram, the voltage needed is the drop voltage in the last resistor from the right. For ohms law we know that

$$ V=RI $$
this apply to the resistor, so 
$$ V_R=RI_R $$

but as this is a RL circuit, the current is given by
$$ \frac{V}{R}(1-e^{-Rt/L}) $$
Having in mind that the resistor is in parallel with another resistor, the current passing through it is:
$$ i_R=\frac{R_t}{r_x}I_t $$
Now, Rt is the total resistance in the parallel arragment, which is 1 ohm, rx is the resistor who we want to know the voltage, which is 2 ohm and It is the current in the RL circuit, so, replacing the values in the formula we have
$$ V_r=R\cdot I $$
$$ V_r=R\cdot \frac{R_t}{r_x}I_t $$
$$ V_r=R\cdot \frac{R_t}{r_x} \cdot \frac{V}{R}(1-e^{-Rt/L}) $$
$$ V_r=2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{12}{3}(1-e^{-3t/2}) $$
$$ V_r=4(1-e^{-3t/2}) $$
which is the formula they give you in the book as anwser for the time from 0 to 1 second. In order to calculate the voltage after one second (when the source voltage is off) I guess you need to calculate the power saved in the inductor all the way to 1 second and then calculate how (turn into voltage) decrease with the resistor in the circuit.

Here is a graphic of the voltage in that one second.
[image: Voltage characterization]

from there on, as in the book says, you must use another equation which so far, I don't know the origin.

Greetings

Info about the equation of the current through the inductor http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/lr-circuits.html